# Error with MSVC only: use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

This compiles fine without errors on both clang and gcc, but fails with MSVC: ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/4FwGc0))

```
// detection idiom

template <class...>
using void_t = void;

template <class Void, template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector_base
{
     using type = void;
};

template <template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector_base<void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>
{
    using type = Op<Args...>;
};

template <class T>
using check = decltype(T::x);

template <typename T>
struct type {};

using dt = typename detector_base<void, check, int>::type; // this is void
using t = type<dt>;
// ^--- 't': use of class template requires template argument list
```

This occurs when using the detected type with any template type. Is this a compiler bug, or is due to lack of support (if so, for what)?

Comment: really good question!

Comment: Anyway, ["Alias templates: Type replacement may fail if an alias template has dependent expression or decltype in it. Our current implementation of alias templates uses type replacement and reparsing of the token stream from the old parser. The latter is used for dependent expression and decltype, but the context in which the reparsing is done isn’t always correct.If you use this kind of alias templates in a SFINAE context the result are currently unpredictable "](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/).

Comment: @T.C. that might be why. If you want to, post a full answer. Also, is_convertible was just me forgetting to update the message. Should be fixed now

Comment: It is fixed in the latest MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d5nxfqGEM